# How to save .contents().clone() object into sessionStorage

Tags: jquery, object, clone, sessionstorage

I'm trying to save `$('#container-geral').contents().clone();` into sessionStorage but I'm getting this error:

> Converting circular structure to JSON

My code is

```
 var $dataAtual = $('#container').contents().clone();           
 sessionStorage.setItem("name", JSON.stringify($dataAtual));
```

The object is:

```
[text, div, prevObject: e.fn.init[2], context: document, jquery: "1.10.2", constructor: function, init: function…]0: text1: divcontext: documentlength: 2prevObject: e.fn.init[2]__proto__: Object[0
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: You can't serialise/stringify jQuery objects. Don't confuse it with pure javascript objects. You need to rip it apart and create a new object, which you then can stringify. This thread might point you in the right direction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8914985/javascript-how-to-serialize-a-dom-element-as-a-string-to-be-used-later

Comment: The problem is that a key in that includes the object again (here the `document` is included a lot of times, meaning json.stringify will run infinite numbers of time because document includes this object as well)