# Phantomjs dump dom object

Tags: phantomjs

I'm new to Phantomjs. For debugging on a remote server, I often want to dump a DOM object to look at the structure (similar to Data::Dumper in Perl). This currently is for scraping a couple of sites.

I've thought JSON.stringify may help with this, but it still displays an object name like "[object HTMLDocument]"

Edit: I have also looked at [JavaScript: how to serialize a DOM element as a string to be used later?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8914985) , but I can't seem to inject jquery in phantomjs (still looking for a solution to that, and would prefer no depencencies), and the other answer doesn't seem to work. As I assume it would be a common case for Phantom to analyse the DOM, I thought it would be common for phantom users to have a solution to this.

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var system = require('system');

page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg) {
        console.log( msg );
}

page.open('http://www.test.com', function(status) {
       if(status !== "success") {
                console.log( status );
       } else {
                page.evaluate(function() {

                    var headline = document.querySelectorAll('div');
                    console.log(  JSON.stringify( headline )  ); // HERE???

                });
        }
        phantom.exit();
});
```

Is there any way to do this, or am I approaching this wrong ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript: how to serialize a DOM element as a string to be used later?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8914985/javascript-how-to-serialize-a-dom-element-as-a-string-to-be-used-later)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `page.evaluate()`, you can use `XMLSerializer.serializeToString()` to convert  whatever DOM node you want to string.

```
page.evaluate(function() {
    var s = new XMLSerializer();
    return s.serializeToString(document.getElementById('div'));
});
```

I haven't tried it with "querySelectorAll", since it may return array instead of standalone DOM node, but it definitely works for DOM nodes.

[MDN Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XMLSerializer)