# how to force puppeteer to wait for XMLHttpRequests to end, etc, and get finished version of DOM?

Tags: javascript, dom, puppeteer

I currently have a web page that loads some elements dynamically via `XMLHttpRequest`. Here is what the javascript portion of that looks like:

```
function loadHtmlSnippet(filename, callback) {
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
            parser = new DOMParser()
            minidoc = parser.parseFromString(xmlHttp.responseText, "text/html")
            minibody = minidoc.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]
            callback(minibody)
        }
    };

    xmlHttp.open("GET", 'http://localhost:3000/' + filename, true);
    xmlHttp.send(null);
}
```

This is used by making a call like...

```
loadHtmlSnippet('my_extra_html_piece.html', my_appropriate_callback)
```

...where `my_appropriate_callback` is a function that inserts the `my_extra_html_piece.html` DOM at some appropriate place in the main page's DOM.

So far so good, it works!

Next, I would like to get my hands on the finished DOM, in the form of a string, after all this loading is over. I have been trying to use Chromium `puppeteer` for this. Here's my puppeteer node.js script:

```
const express = require('express')
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')

url = process.argv[2]

async function ssr(url) {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: true
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(url, {
        waitUntil: 'networkidle0'
    });
    html = await page.content();
    await browser.close();
    return html;
}

async function start() {
    html = await ssr(url)
    console.log(html)
}

start()
```

(I basically cut-pasted this from a puppeteer tutorial.)

Alas, the above script returns me the DOM after some javascript processing has been done, but not after the `XMLHttpRequest`s have finished loading and their respective HTMLs inserted into the main DOM.

Is there some way to force puppeteer to wait for the javascript to really be finished spinning before saving the rendered html and closing?

====

Aside: I've had some luck with the serialization methods discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8914985/javascript-how-to-serialize-a-dom-element-as-a-string-to-be-used-later), but as I use puppeteer for other things it would be nice if I could do this part of the DOM serialization via puppeteer as well. (So the question is puppeteer-specific.)

Comment: You can use [page.waitForResponse](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v1.7.0&show=api-pagewaitforresponseurlorpredicate-options)

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be it. (Documentation was a bit rough around the edges, though the below-mentioned `page.waitForNavigation` has better docs, for similar options.) In some ways `page.waitForRequest` could be even more useful: I can install a dummy XMLHttpRequest that the javascript fires only when *it* has decided everything is done, and puppeteer will wait for that! (The problem being that a `response` might be followed by some itty-bitty more page processing, that I don't want to get lost.)

Comment: `page.waitForRequest` start when you request start and you got a `Request` obj, you need to acces to the method `request.response()` to get the `Response` obj where you can get the string with `response.text()`, is fine but with `page.waitForResponse` you'll get the `Response` obj directly... maybe you don't need the `Request` obj

Comment: waitForResponse doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

await page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded' });

Comment: I think `page.waitForResponse` (or even `page.waitForRequest`, as mentioned in my comment above) suggested by @kip might be more appropriate, but I'll accept your answer since you have a mere 23 reputation :)